# HTML Imagemap - Border

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add a css border to a [HTML Imagemap](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp)?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711402/2397550

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there's a cross browser CSS solution, but this jQuery plugin can do what you're after:
[jQuery MapHilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/)

It can show the border without hover if you specify `alwaysOn:true`, as seen on the first example there (the black part is done using the plugin).

Answer (score 1):

2 option :

1 - wrap your image with div and give him border .

2 - build your image map with divs + css background images

like in this example :

http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/css-image-maps-a-beginners-guide-/