# Adding hover effects for links in image map (area)

Tags: css, hover, imagemap

I'm only a beginner in html and I would like to put hover effects for my image map. I have searched for lots of solutions but I only come up with solutions using script which I don't understand.

How does this script work? I tried using

```
area:hover {
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: That's CSS, not script. It goes in your stylesheet.

Comment: sorry bout that, I didn't mean to add the word 'this'. lol sorry

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is not very simple, you will have to combine javascript and css or jquery to give the effect you want.

It's because the `area` element doesn't accept `hover` directly, unfortunately...

But the good news is that it was answered before here:

[How to apply Hovering on html area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag)

[Visible Area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag)

Answer (score 2):

The following JS and CSS makes image(map)s responsive and adds a hover effect to the areas.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[usemap]');
images.forEach( function(image) {
    var mapid = image.getAttribute('usemap').substr(1);
    var imagewidth = image.getAttribute('width');
    var imageheight = image.getAttribute('height');
    var imagemap = document.querySelector('map[name="'+mapid+'"]');
    var areas = imagemap.querySelectorAll('area');

    image.removeAttribute('usemap');
    imagemap.remove();

    // create wrapper container
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('imagemap');
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, image);
    wrapper.appendChild(image);

    areas.forEach( function(area) {
        var coords = area.getAttribute('coords').split(',');
        var xcoords = [parseInt(coords[0]),parseInt(coords[2])];
        var ycoords = [parseInt(coords[1]),parseInt(coords[3])];
        xcoords = xcoords.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        ycoords = ycoords.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        wrapper.innerHTML += "<a href='"+area.getAttribute('href')+"' title='"+area.getAttribute('title')+"' class='area' style='left: "+((xcoords[0]/imagewidth)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; top: "+((ycoords[0]/imageheight)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; width: "+(((xcoords[1] - xcoords[0])/imagewidth)*100).toFixed(2)+"%; height: "+(((ycoords[1] - ycoords[0])/imageheight)*100).toFixed(2)+"%;'></a>";
    });
});
```

```css
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}

.imagemap {position: relative;}
.imagemap img {display: block;}
.imagemap .area {display: block; position: absolute; transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;}
.imagemap .area:hover {box-shadow: 0px 0px 1vw rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

```html
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/TwmCyCX.jpg" width="2000" height="2604" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="Zirconia Abutment" title="Zirconia Abutment" href="/" coords="3,12,199,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Gold Abutment" title="Gold Abutment" href="/" coords="245,12,522,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="CCM Abutment" title="CCM Abutment" href="/" coords="564,12,854,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="EZ Post Abutment" title="EZ Post Abutment" href="/" coords="1036,12,1360,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Milling Abutment" title="Milling Abutment" href="/" coords="1390,12,1688,369" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Angled Abutment" title="Angled Abutment" href="/" coords="1690,12,1996,371" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Temporary Abutment [Metal]" title="Temporary Abutment [Metal]" href="/" coords="45,461,506,816" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Fuse Abutment" title="Fuse Abutment" href="/" coords="1356,461,1821,816" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Lab Analog" title="Lab Analog" href="/" coords="718,935,1119,1256" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Transfer Impression Coping Driver" title="Transfer Impression Coping Driver" href="/" coords="8,1330,284,1731" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Impression Coping [Transfer]" title="Impression Coping [Transfer]" href="/" coords="310,1330,697,1731" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Impression Coping [Pick-Up]" title="Impression Coping [Pick-Up]" href="/" coords="1116,1330,1560,1733" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Comment: this solution will work only for rectangles and may be circles, but not for polygons